# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError - migrating from one server to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm new to Rails so please bear with me.

Currently there is an existing project (Rails 4.1.6, Ruby 2.1.3) running on digital ocean VM (Ubuntu 14.04) and its connecting to Postgresdb 9.6 without any issues. I have to migrate this to new VM.

I have setup a new vm with Ubuntu 16.04, installed Rails and Ruby with exact same versions. I tried creating a test rails app and its working fine. However, when I tried to deployed the project from old server to this new one its giving me errors.

```
Details:

There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'.
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See   https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs  /runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib  /active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
```

After searching on internet, most of them suggested to uncomment this line in the Gemfile.

```
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
```

This was commented in the old server, however, I tried uncommenting it and it came back with different error.

```
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

Website was connecting to the same database and old webportal was running fine but it gave me this error. So I setup a new test db and ran the following commands -

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:setup
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

All those commands were executed successfully but for some reason I'm still receiving "Migrations are pending....." error.

Please advise.

Comment: When you say "run a test" do you mean an rspec test or other automated test?

Comment: The migration-error seems to think you should be on the `development` environment... but the migrations you ran are for `production`... so either your environment-setting is not correct, or you need to run the migrations for `development` instead

Comment: @Taryn East Thank you.. I was such a stupid. I checked the nginx sites-available file and there passenger env was set to development. I changed it to production and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Cool. stupid bugs are the best - so easy to fix :D I'll make my comment an answer so you can accept it and mark your question solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration-error seems to think you should be on the `development` environment... but the migrations you ran are for `production`... so either your environment-setting is not correct, or you need to run the migrations for `development` instead